# Why does the main process code not execute after join() method

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Why does the main process code not execute after join() method. I think the code line "print('mater gone')" should be execute after two sub threads running finished, but it's not actually. 
  My step like this:

```
# cc.py
import time, multiprocessing, signal, threading, random, time, queue

class Master(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Master,self).__init__();
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.handler);
        self.live = {'stat':True};                   

    def handler(self, signum, frame):
        print('signal:',signum);
        self.live['stat'] = 0;

    def run(self):
        print('PID:',self.pid);     
        cond = threading.Condition(threading.Lock());
        q = queue.Queue();
        sender = Sender(cond, self.live, q);
        geter = Geter(cond, self.live, q);
        sender.start();
        geter.start();
        while threading.activeCount()-1:
            time.sleep(2);
            print('checking live', threading.activeCount());
        print('mater gone');
        sender.join();
        geter.join();

class Sender(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cond, live, queue):
        super(Sender, self).__init__(name='sender');
        self.cond = cond;
        self.queue = queue;
        self.live = live

    def run(self):
        cond = self.cond;
        while self.live['stat']:
            cond.acquire();
            i = random.randint(0,100);
            self.queue.put(i,False);
            if not self.queue.full():
                print('sender add:',i);
            cond.notify();
            cond.release();
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,3));
        print('sender done')

class Geter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cond, live, queue):
        super(Geter, self).__init__(name='geter');
        self.cond = cond;
        self.queue = queue;
        self.live = live

    def run(self):
        cond = self.cond;
        while self.live['stat']:
            cond.acquire();
            if not self.queue.empty():
                i = self.queue.get();
                print('geter get:',i);
            cond.wait(3);
            cond.release();
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,3));
        print('geter done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Master();
    master.start();  

--session1
C:\PrivateData>python cc.py
The outout like this:
PID: 14320
sender add: 75
geter get: 75
checking live 3
sender add: 67
checking live 3
sender add: 79
geter get: 67
checking live 3
checking live 3
sender add: 69

--session2
>>> import os,signal,time
>>> os.kill(14320,signal.SIGTERM)
```

When I send os.kill command in session2, The output in session1 stop immediately without 'mater gone', I think the main process shouldn't end after sub threads stop, am i have any problems?

Comment: How is `if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Master();
    master.start();`
being called? I do not see a `.start()` function in `Master` class. There is a '.run()' defined. Are you sure you want to be calling `.start()` or do you want to call `.run()`? It could be that your `master` object is not calling the function you want.

Comment: I think because the Master inherit multiprocessing.Process, so why the .start() function need in Master Class? I usually use start() after class instance.

Comment: You should be calling `.run()` if you want to use `.run()`. Otherwise, you are not using that function.